# select * vs select column: different number of rows

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Why are these two MySQL sentences returning different number of rows?

**They only differ in the select.**

Query #1: 4586 rows

```
select *
from `pedidos`
inner join `tipos_entrada` on `pedidos`.`tipo_entrada_id` = `tipos_entrada`.`id`
inner join `eventos` on `tipos_entrada`.`evento_id` = `eventos`.`id`
inner join `users` on `pedidos`.`usuario_id` = `users`.`id`;
```

Query #2: 2805 rows

```
select pedidos.id,
    pedidos.ds_merchant_order,
    pedidos.created_at,
    users.email as usuario_email,
    eventos.nombre as evento_nombre,
    tipos_entrada.nombre as tipo_entrada_nombre,
    pedidos.estado,
    pedidos.cantidad,
    pedidos.precio,
    pedidos.precio * pedidos.cantidad as total
from `pedidos`
inner join `tipos_entrada` on `pedidos`.`tipo_entrada_id` = `tipos_entrada`.`id`
inner join `eventos` on `tipos_entrada`.`evento_id` = `eventos`.`id`
inner join `users` on `pedidos`.`usuario_id` = `users`.`id`;
```

Why the fact of adding the columns affects in the number of rows?
I tried different combinations of removing the columns from the select but just one column already alters the result. Only "*" returns the total number of rows in the table.

Edit: changing the inner join with users to left join returns the 4586 rows.

Comment: If you are only changing the column list and aren’t adding aggregated then this sounds like a bug. You should share the exact version you are running, and it’s worth checking the behaviour on the most recent version.

Comment: What provided "nnnn rows"?  `EXPLAIN` only gives an estimate.